# Is there any direct way to get a minimal HTML node structure in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodes

This is the input node structure

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL1</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL2</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL3</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL4</span></div></div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</th>
            <td>content 2</td>
            <td>content 3</td>
            <td>content 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the wanted output structure

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>COL1</th>
            <th>COL2</th>
            <th>COL3</th>
            <th>COL4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</th>
            <td>content 2</td>
            <td>content 3</td>
            <td>content 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I could just remove the elements manually with some mappings or some loops, but I am wondering if there is a better way to just get the minimal HTML possible without attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the attributes you can use the `removeAttr`,.

To get rid of `<div><div><span>...`,. You could loop the `th` get the `text()` and then set using `text()` again this has the effect of getting rid of the the extra tags.

eg..

```js
const c = $('table').clone();

c.find('*').removeAttr('class style');
c.find('th').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).text()); }); 

console.log(c[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL1</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL2</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL3</span></div></div></th>
            <th class="some_class"><div><div><span>COL4</span></div></div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</td>
            <td>content 2</td>
            <td>content 3</td>
            <td>content 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do `c.find('*').removeAttr('class style');` I get the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. So if I wanted to make it like that I would need to do it with small selections to get it done

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's pretty easy...

Here i have a codesandbox for you where this works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-star-g8h8f?file=/index.html

```
  $(".noattrs *").each(function() {
    // first copy the attributes to remove
    // if we don't do this it causes problems
    // iterating over the array we're removing
    // elements from
    var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });

    // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
    var el = $(this);
    $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
      el.removeAttr(item);
    });
  })
```

Comment: inseat of the answer from Keith
this removes all attributes without hardcoding each removeAttr.

Comment: Yes, I see, that's interesting, thank you. I will mix both answers because I also need to do `c.find('th').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).text()); });` to remove the extra nodes in each cell

Comment: exactly, would do the same